# Restrict user going to the inner page without login using angular-ui-route

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular project. In that if i type in the url as "dashboard" it is redirecting to "dashboard.html" page. But i want to restrict user going into that page without successfully logged In.

Below in my routing code please check.

**index.js**

```
angular.module('adminsuite',['ui.router','ngCookies']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        views:{
            pageContent:{
                templateUrl: 'Login/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            },
            footer:{
                templateUrl: 'common/footer.html',
                controller: 'footerController'
            }
        }



    })
    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
     .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views:{
            header:{
                templateUrl: 'common/header.html',
                controller: 'headerController'
            },
            pageContent:{
                templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
                 controller: 'dashboardController'
            },
            footer:{
                templateUrl: 'common/footer.html',
                controller: 'footerController'
            }
        }
    })
    //SURVEY STATES
    .state('survey', {
        url: '/survey',
        views:{
            header:{
                templateUrl: 'common/headerTool.html',
                controller: 'headerController'
            },
            pageContent:{
                templateUrl: 'survey/survey.html',
                  controller: 'surveyController'
            },
            footer:{
                templateUrl: 'common/footer.html',
                controller: 'footerController'
            }
        }
    });

    // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================

});
```

Comment: you can use a service to create a function that checks if a user is logged in, it should return true or false... then from whichever page you want to restrict , call that function in it's controller, something like this:  `if(!User.logged_in) {//...redirect them to login page}`

Comment: Please keep in mind that this should only be used for UX design ( eg. not showing a section of site that lack use or functionality for that user ) and not for blocking access to content which should always happen on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your loginController store value in $rootscope if user sucessfully logged in.

```
if(userloggedin == true )
{
  $rootscope.loggedinuser = true
}
```

in your dashboardController get value from $rootscope and check if  $rootscope.loggedinuser is equal to true then dasboard.html page will show otherwise page redirect to login page.

in your dashboardController

```
if($rootscope.loggedinuser !=true)
{
    $state.go('login');
}
```

Comment: yes u can use this code for surveyController. please vote up if answer is acceptable.

Comment: I am using this solution... But now I have dozens of controllers and getting difficult to maintain in all controllers.. Is there any single place solution like directive or anything??

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing. In your `loginController` create a variable and store that in `local storage` if the user successfully logged in. And in your `dashboard` routing statement resolve that data from local storage. The page will load to `/dashboard` only if it can resolve that data. If he is not logged in the resolving data will be undefined

```
.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views:{
        header:{
            templateUrl: 'common/header.html',
            controller: 'headerController'
        },
        pageContent:{
            templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
             controller: 'dashboardController'
        },
        footer:{
            templateUrl: 'common/footer.html',
            controller: 'footerController'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
       accessToken: ['$localStorage', function($localStorage){
           return $localStorage.accessToken
        }]
    }
})
```

**OR your resolve code can be like**

```
resolve: {
   accessToken: ['$localStorage','$state', function($localStorage, $state){
       if($localStorage.accessToken)
         return $localStorage.accessToken
       else{
         $state.go(login)
         return;
       }
    }]
}
```

here variable **`accessToken` is storing to `$localStorage` in your `loginController` as**

```
if('successfully logged in'){
  $localStorage.accessToken = 'a random value';
}
```

You can use `sessionStorage`, `$cookieStore` etc. instead of `$localStorage`. It's option of you.

There is **one more** option. **Broadcasting a variable** when login happens and resolve that data in dashboard

Comment: Can i use $rootScope instead of $localStorage.

Comment: @KISHANPATI Sure you can. But make sure one thing, whatever you are using, `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or `rootScope` **Don't forget to clear that when the user logged out**

Comment: Incase you're using $rootScope to save token, then token will be lost if user refreshes the page. Be aware of this case before proceeding with $rootScope

Comment: I have used the above code and its not working. Is it because of multiple views in the state

Comment: What error is coming.. Anyway, I will update my answer with one more option.

Edit: Updated the answer